# Darboux integral definition in wikipedia

Tags: riemann-integration

At some point, wikipedia says that

> An equivalent and sometimes useful criterion for the integrability of $f$ is to show that for every $ε > 0$ there exists a partition $P_ε$ on $[a,b]$ such that
>
> $$U_{f,P_{\epsilon}}-L_{f,P_{\epsilon}} < \epsilon.$$

My question has to do with using $\epsilon$ both for the upper and lower sums and also for the partition (Intuitively, the physical units would not match...).

Shouldn't we use instead a epson-delta definition like the following?

$$\forall \epsilon>0\quad\exists\delta: U_{f,P_{\delta}}-L_{f,P_{\delta}} < \epsilon.$$

Are they equivalent?

Comment: They are just numbers (they aren't free men), no units in sight. (Besides, $\varepsilon$ is just an _index_ of $P_{\varepsilon}$.)

Comment: @Daniel I was understanding $P_\epsilon$ as meaning the partition where the max subinterval has size $\epsilon$. Not sure what it means.

Comment: No, it's just some partition for which the upper and lower Darboux sum differ by less than $\varepsilon$. If $f$ is constant on long subintervals, the mesh of the partition may be quite large.

Comment: They wrote $P_\epsilon$ meaning some partition (depending on $\epsilon$.)  We do not know, or need to know, anything about the mesh of that partition.